# Odata v4 ODataModelBuilder relations builder

Tags: linq, web-services, odata, odata-v4

i'm working to implement web api using OData v4 
my database structure is seperate tables the relations between my tables should be represent inside Enitiy Framework 
i had implement my EF model for my database structuer as following:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
   builder.EntitySet<tabl1>("tabl1").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.ID);
   builder.EntitySet<tabl2>("tabl2").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.ID);
   builder.EntitySet<tabl3>("tabl3").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.ID);
   builder.EntitySet<tabl4>("tabl4").EntityType.HasKey(p => p.ID);
   config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataroute",
            routePrefix: "api",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

how can i implement relationship between my tables
so i can be able to use query like this or if i can use normal linq Query action from my controller but it's not working with me
http://localhost:13193/api/table1?$expand=table2

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which EF technic you are using. If you are using `code-first` you just need to set the relation inside you model definition. The following model builds a `1 : n` relation between `tabl1` and `tabl2`:

```
public class tabl1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual tabl2 tabl2 { get; set; }
}

public class tabl2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tabl2> tabl2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It's right.

$expand is used to expand a navigation property. In Web API OData, you can directly add a navigation property as Jan written and the Convention model builder will set the *tabl2* in class tabl1 as 1: 1 relationship, and set *tabl2* in class tabl2 as 1: n relationship.